# XMLTABLE extract element's posision()

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have XML like:

```
<all>
    <cell>
        <data>A</data>
        <data>A1</data>
        <data>A2</data>
        <data>A3</data>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <data>B</data>
        <data>C</data>
        <data>D</data>
        <data>E</data>
    </cell>
    <cell>
        <data>X</data>
        <data>X</data>
        <data>X</data>
        <data>X</data>
    </cell>
</all>
```

I want to extract in table content on every all/cell/data and unique path to the element. There aren't IDs in attributes or another unique mark and my idea for unique path is for example:

**/all/cell[2]/data[5]**

Expected result(example XML) is:

```
Content | Path
----------------------
A       |/all/cell[1]/data[1]
A1      |/all/cell[1]/data[2]
A2      |/all/cell[1]/data[3]
A3      |/all/cell[1]/data[4]
B       |/all/cell[2]/data[1]
C       |/all/cell[2]/data[2]
D       |/all/cell[2]/data[3]
E       |/all/cell[2]/data[4]
X       |/all/cell[3]/data[1]
X       |/all/cell[3]/data[2]
X       |/all/cell[3]/data[3]
X       |/all/cell[3]/data[4]
```

I tried using XMLTABLE to call *posision()* of elements but it returns only "1" for every element.

```
select b.*
  from dropme a,
       xmltable('/all/cell/data' passing
                xmltype(xml_text) columns 
                cmp_old varchar2(200) path 'text()', -- work corect!
                cmp_old1 varchar2(200) path '.', -- work corect! Result is same as cmp_old(upper filed)
                rowcnt number path 'position()', -- return only value "1"
                rowname varchar2(200) path 'name()', -- work corect! Return "data" as result
                parent_rowcnt number path '../position()', -- return only value "1"
                parent_rowname varchar2(200) path '../name()' -- work corect! Return "cell" as result
                ) b;
```

I can't understand why it works for functions *name()* and *text()* but there is problem with *position()*.

I try to find problem with *position()* or another solution to extract path and content of all element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use multiple correlated `XMLTABLE` with `FOR ORDINALITY` instead of `position()`:

```sql
select b.cell_no,
       b.cell_name,
       c.*
from   dropme a
       CROSS JOIN
       xmltable(
         '/all/cell'
         passing xmltype(xml_text)
         columns
           cell_no   FOR ORDINALITY,
           cell_name VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'name()',
           cell      XMLType       PATH '.'
       ) b
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/cell/data'
         PASSING b.cell
         COLUMNS
           cmp_old varchar2(200) path 'text()',
           rowcnt FOR ORDINALITY,
           rowname varchar2(200) path 'name()'
       ) c;
```

> ```
> CELL_NO | CELL_NAME | CMP_OLD | ROWCNT | ROWNAME
> ------: | :-------- | :------ | -----: | :------
>       1 | cell      | A       |      1 | data   
>       1 | cell      | A1      |      2 | data   
>       1 | cell      | A2      |      3 | data   
>       1 | cell      | A3      |      4 | data   
>       2 | cell      | B       |      1 | data   
>       2 | cell      | C       |      2 | data   
>       2 | cell      | D       |      3 | data   
>       2 | cell      | E       |      4 | data   
>       3 | cell      | X       |      1 | data   
>       3 | cell      | X       |      2 | data   
>       3 | cell      | X       |      3 | data   
>       3 | cell      | X       |      4 | data
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=305d85f7c767ffb6d3b6086f81cb0433)*